# Starting with PySpark and having problems with simple code

Tags: java, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, cmd

I'm new with PySpark and tried a simple code like that

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Read File')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

rdd = sc.textFile('data1.txt')
print(rdd.collect())

rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
print(rdd2.collect())
```

but the `rdd2.collect()` execution always give me problems like:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)/ 2]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
```

I have this versions installed all local and executing in Windows 10 with cmd.exe:

- Python 3.12.1
- Java 11.0.20
- Spark 3.5.0
- Hadoop 3.3.6

I also have declared all the environment variables, `JAVA_HOME`, `SCALA_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME`, `SPARK_HOME`, `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`. Last 2 with the route to python.exe on the Python instalation route.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall everything, change versions, change environment variables but I do not know what to do now.

Comment: Maybe I should use Spark and PySpark on docker, so, should I learn to creat and work with dockers?

Comment: Use databricks, far easier.

Comment: I am looking at "Python 3.12", while it might seems [benign](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html#python-versions-supported), I will still check by downgrading to python 3.8 (9 or 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have finished using docker with the specific image of pyspark in jupyter "https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook" and it works correctly without problems, in case there is someone interested that has this kind of problems you can also follow this guide "https://medium.com/@suci/running-pyspark-on-jupyter-notebook-with-docker-602b18ac4494" and this "https://subhamkharwal.medium.com/data-lakehouse-with-pyspark-setup-pyspark-docker-jupyter-lab-env-1261a8a55697".

Thanks to this I was able to install docker easily and load the "jupyter/pyspark-notebook" image correctly so everything works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, after downgrading python to 3.8.10 all seems to be working fine.

Comment: Downgrading Python isn't a viable solution for most people.

Comment: I'm sorry it isn't for you, it was for me and all my colleagues.